# Action after dismiss modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this function to create my modal:

```
function modalAlert(text)
{
    if($('#modalToRemove'))
        $('#modalToRemove').remove();
    $('<div id="modalToRemove" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button><h4 class="modal-title">TITLE</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><h4>'+text+'</h4></div><div class="modal-footer"> <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></div></div></div></div>').modal();
}
```

And I would like to do an action after closing the modal.
I tried this code but not working...

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Can you suggest me any thing else?

Thanks!!

Comment: `if($('#modalToRemove'))` UM, that is ALWAYS true. It returns a Jquery object which is truthy. You would need to check the length. BUT why bother since you can chain without error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling $('#modalToRemove').on(...) instead of $('#myModal').on(...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you binding it after you add the element to the page?

```js
function modalAlert (text) {
    $('#modalToRemove').remove();
    $('<div id="modalToRemove" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button><h4 class="modal-title">TITLE</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><h4>'+text+'</h4></div><div class="modal-footer"> <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></div></div></div></div>').modal();
    $('#modalToRemove').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      alert("xxx");
    });
}

modalAlert("hey");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you are binding the event outside of it, you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modalToRemove', function () {
    alert("xxx");
});
```